# Compile error using cl.exe (Visual Studio 2008) for this cpp code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction

I'm getting compile error in this code

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdio>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;
    void main(int argc,char *argv[])
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0;i<10;i++)
           fprintf(cout,"%d\n",i);
        fprintf(cout,"abc:\n");
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        if(s == "resume") { 
            for(i = 0;i<10;i++)
            fprintf(cout,"%d\n",i);
        }
   }
```

Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.21022.08 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

try.cpp
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : warning C
4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify
/EHsc

try.cpp(9) : error C2664: 'fprintf' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::ostr
eam' to 'FILE *'
        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conv
ersion, or the operator cannot be called

try.cpp(10) : error C2664: 'fprintf' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::ost
ream' to 'FILE *'
        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conv
ersion, or the operator cannot be called

try.cpp(16) : error C2664: 'fprintf' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::ost
ream' to 'FILE *'
        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conv
ersion, or the operator cannot be called

what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::fprintf(stdout, )
```

Answer (score 6):

You are mixing up C++ and C output styles. Change your fprintfs to look like:

```
cout << "value is: " << i << "\n";
```

Comment: Or use printf("...",...) instead of fprintf(cout,"...",...)

Answer (score 2):

std::cout has no FILE* type.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, change your includes to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

and the `fprintf()` calls to

```
fprintf(stdout,"abc:\n");
```

Then you're talking `C`.

Comment: in c++ it is better to include <cstdio>

Comment: I was spelling out the *C* alternative - not C++.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixin C and C++ incorrectly. Use only 1, and stick to it untill you learn what the difference between the types are.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code without compilation errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout << i << '\n';
  cout << "abc" << endl;

  string s;
  cin >> s;
  if(s == "resume") 
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      cout << i << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```